# Javascript not completing execution

Tags: javascript

I am not a coder and just learning. I am using this script from a module in `opencart`. It works fine in terms of posting an email to database. In unsubscribe it works fine clearing the entry box and giving the successful unsubscribe message. However, when registering an email it does post the email correctly but does not clear the entry box or give the success message. I have tried a few things but cannot seem to get it to post correctly. Can anybody help to work out the problem?

```
<script language="javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#lt_newsletter_form').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<?php echo $action; ?>',
                data: $("#lt_newsletter_form").serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $('.btn-newsletter').attr('disabled', true).button('loading');
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $('.btn-newsletter').attr('disabled', false).button('reset');
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
                    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

                    if (json.error) {
                        $('#lt_newsletter_module').after('<div class="alert alert-danger newsletter-msg">' + json.error + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                    } else {
                        $('#lt_newsletter_module').after('<div class="alert alert-success newsletter-msg">' + json.success + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                        $('#lt_newsletter_email').val('');
                    }
                }

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the console (f12)?

Comment: Thanks for an immediate response. I am sorry I don't understand the comment.

Comment: Open the browser console (hit f12) and see if there are any errors there

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. I have done this but no errors are recorded and there are none in error logs

Comment: "*In unsubscribe it works fine*" - can you post that code as well? Also show the respective markup.

Comment: Remove ```return``` and check.

Comment: Hi. The calling code is:  if ((utf8_strlen($email) > 96) || !preg_match('/^[^\@]+@.*.[a-z]{2,15}$/i', $email)) {
    $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_invalid');
   }
   else{
    $row = $this->model_module_lt_newsletter->row($email);
    if($row)
    {
     $this->model_module_lt_newsletter->unsubscribe($email);
     $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_unsubscribed');
    }
    else{
     $this->model_module_lt_newsletter->subscribe($email);
     $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_subscribed');

Comment: Removing 'return' fails to make the code work.

Comment: Hi Bergi. Following your comment earlier has the code thrown any light on the issue?